# how to seach and print realpath version in tcl?

Tags: unix, tcl, tclsh

Suppose a path x/y/z has 5 directories i.e 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5. now I want to print only that directories names which is greater than 1.1. if in another path a/b/c same directories is present, but 1.2 dir is missing, then it should print 1.3 as the next directory is higher than 1.1? How to do that in tclsh???

Comment: Are you talking about files with those names? Or strings?

Comment: directories with names of different version.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about filenames here? Of directories?

To get a list of directories in a location that match a pattern like that, you might use:

```
# d for “directory”
set names [glob -directory a/b/c -type d {[0-9]*.[0-9]*}]
```

That's going to be in random order (well, it depends on a vast number of factors in the OS so pretending it is random is much simpler!) and *might* have some false positives in it. We need to filter and sort. Fortunately, we have `package vsatisfies` to do the parsing.

```
set filtered [lmap name $names {
    try {
        if {[package vsatisfies [file tail $name] 1.1]} {
            set name
        } else continue
    } on error {} continue
}]
# You'll find that dictionary sorting does the Right Thing in this case
set sorted [lsort -dictionary $filtered]
```

All that's left now is to print the elements in the list out. The maximum item in it is `[lindex $sorted end]`…

Comment: If you want to use full pathnames, the easiest way is to normalize the input directory.`glob -directory [file normalize a/b/c] ...`

Comment: am talking about directories.
Am talking about directories. Suppose a path x/y/z has 5 directories i.e 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5. now I want to print only that directories names with is greater than 1.1. if in another path a/b/c same directories is present, but 1.2 dir is missing, then it should print 1.3 as the next directory is higher than 1.1? How to do that in tclsh???