# how to search and print the real path of a directory (which is version > 1.1)?

Tags: unix, tcl, tclsh

Suppose the path `x/y/z` has 5 directories i.e.:

```
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
```

Now I want to print only those directory names which are greater than `1.1`.

If in another path `a/b/c` the same directories are present, but `1.2` directory is missing, then it should print `1.3` as the next directory, which is higher than `1.1`.

How to do that in `tclsh`?

The output should be like:

```
x/y/z/{version higher than 1.1}
```

For example:

```
x/y/z/1.2
```

or

```
x/y/z/1.4
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to seach and print realpath version in tcl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68616822/how-to-seach-and-print-realpath-version-in-tcl)

Comment: hi @Shawn nop its doesnt work